# How to search and return a range of a slice using iterators?

Tags: rust, iterator, slice

Suppose I have the following slice:

```rust
let src = &[7, 4, 5, 0, 3, 6, 0, 2, 5];
```

I need to perform two steps:

1. search this slice until I find the first `0`;
2. return all elements up to the found element.

For the slice above, the returned value would be:

```rust
let res = &[7, 4, 5, 0];
```

Then the search would start again, at the first element after the found `0`, returning:

```rust
let res = &[3, 6, 0];
```

And so on...

How to write this with Rust iterators?

Comment: Does the tail get produced, e.g. would `&[2, 5]` be produced as well in this example?

Comment: Yes, it does get produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split_inclusive` to get you an iterator over the results you want, e.g.

```rust
    let src = &[7, 4, 5, 0, 3, 6, 0, 2, 5];

    let mut calc = src.split_inclusive(|n| *n == 0);

    let res1 = &[7, 4, 5, 0];
    let res2 = &[3, 6, 0];

    assert_eq!(calc.next().unwrap(), res1);
    assert_eq!(calc.next().unwrap(), res2);
```